# Filter mobile site page views using GTM in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a site which has same urls for both mobile site and full site available for mobile.
I want to filter only those page views which have been viewed in mobile version of the site. The full site views from mobile devices should not be tracked/filtered.
Since the url for both the site versions is same, I'm finding it difficult to create a filter/view in my Google analytics account.

Comment: custom filter, "include" -> (exclude, respectively) "device category" -> "desktop". Also this is not code related andthus  probably off-topic,

Comment: Since the site is accessible in both Full site view and mobile site view in mobile devices> i want to track only the Mobile Site view viewed in mobile devices. The device category filter will give me results of both mobile site view and full site view viewed in mobiles. I guess using custom dimensions  will be helpful here, not sure

Comment: How do you determine if the full site or the mobile site is displayed (i.e. media queries, a server side mechanism ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is kindof like what @Eike Pierstorff said go to the Admin dashboard > View > Filters > +New Filter > Filter Type: Custom > Include only > Filter Field: Mobile?

This will allow you to filter visitors that visited your site with a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to record the analytics using the Custom dimensions in Google Analytics. I created a separate div with a unique ID which was only present in the mobile layout. Hence any one who would visit the mobile layout of the site, Google analytics was able to track it using the custom dimension. If the div was not present in the layout the value of the custom dimension would be set to full site view of the site